# @ResolutionScope example

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am attempting to use the @ResolutionScope maven annotation (documented [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugins/annotations/ResolutionScope.html)).  Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to put it at the top of my class.

```
@Mojo(name="json-schema-generator-main")
@ResolutionScope ????
public class JsonSchemaGenerator extends AbstractMojo
```

What do I need to put in the ???? area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you check where the ResolutionScope is used to be which is mentioned [the docs it should be put here](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-annotations/index.html):

```java
@Mojo( name = "<goal-name>",
       requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.<scope>,
)
```

Instead as it's own annotation.

Comment: Why is it so hard to find documentation about this on Maven? if it wasn't for StackOverflow...